# Question on maximum foreign key references in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new to SQL and coding in general. I recently found out that a table can reference a maximum of 253 other tables and columns as foreign keys. This caused me to be concerned because I currently have two tables, Orders and Order Details.

**Orders table**

| Order# | Total | DateTime | PaymentMethod | Cashier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2203 | 7.49 | 2021-09-22 10:31:50.560 | Cash | Jimmy |

**Order Details Table**

| ID | Order# | Item | QTY | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2203 | Hotdog | 2 | 2.30 |
| 11 | 2203 | Cookie | 1 | 0.99 |
| 12 | 2203 | BEANS | 3 | 4.20 |

In the *Orders Table*, **Order#** is the **primary key**. In the  *Order Details Table*, **Order#** is the **foreign key**.

Will having foreign key cause an error once I reach 253 Orders? If that's the case, would removing the foreign key be the remedy? If not, I guess I'm just having issues understanding what they mean by maximum referenfce of 253 foreign keys.

Comment: The restriction is on the *number of tables and columns*, not the *number of rows*. Your set up has *one* table reference.

Comment: The limits of 253 outgoing FK references and 10,000 incoming FK references are at the table/column level, defining the constraints, not individual rows containing data. Ref: [Maximum capacity specifications for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not error when you have 253 orders. The 253 orders you mentioned are the number of records (rows) in the table. You can have as many records as your identity column allows in that table or your server storage allows.

The 253 foreign key limit in a table means that only 253 separate columns in a table can have foreign key references to another table. If you reach that amount of foreign keys, then the database and table are badly written/structured as the more foreign keys you have, the more performance issue you get.